# Entity Framework query and filter according to a collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need a very simply query which can be written in sql easly but I couldn't write it with using Entity Framework.

Request:
I have a Folder table and I need to get folders whose "FullPath" contains the following words which is stored in an inmemory collection.

```
Folder Table:
Id          Name        FullPath
06D5DA4D    Settings    Root/Portals/aaa/Version1PRD/Settings
0AF5C112    Settings    Root/Portals/bbb/Version1STG/Settings
E2A989BB    Settings    Root/Portals/ccc/Version1/Settings
B019A05D    Settings    Root/Portals/ddd/Version1STG/Settings
```

My List on my application.

```
List<FolderViewModel> lst = new List<FolderViewModel>();
lst.Add(new FolderViewModel{PortalCode="aaa"});
lst.Add(new FolderViewModel{PortalCode="bbb"});
```

And what I want to do is to get an sql statement like below, with linq.

```
SELECT TOP 100 Id,Name,F.FullPath
FROM Folder F
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 'aaa' AS Code
  UNION
  SELECT 'bbb'
 ) AS P ON F.FullPath LIKE 'Root/Portals/' + P.Code + '/%/Settings'
```

which will result

```
Id          Name        FullPath
06D5DA4D    Settings    Root/Portals/aaa/Version1PRD/Settings
0AF5C112    Settings    Root/Portals/bbb/Version1STG/Settings
```

I couldn't imagine how to write a query like above, maybe this can't be written on linq but I'm not sure that it can or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can indeed be written in LINQ, as so:

```
var portalCodes = lst.Select(f => f.PortalCode).Distinct();
var folders = dbContext.Folders.Where(f => portalCodes.Any(p => f.FullPath.Contains(p)));
```